# iOS - Submission of app review simulation

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there a way to simulate the review of app during submission on Apple Store?

During submission, there are instances where the build got rejected for some reason. So, what I want to know and/or achieve is to simulate this review so on future releases, I'd already know whether there's something wrong with my build before submitting it on Apple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to the App Store submission process and is not specifically about programming. It could be asked on other sites on the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 0):

At the Organizer window besides the "Upload to App Store" button, you also have the "Validate" button - this is what you are looking for.